# USERFORM: Qual a diferença das rotinas Initialize e Activate?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, eventos, userform

Qual a diferença de se usar `Initialize` e `Activate` como rotina de inicialização de um UserForm?

1. `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()`
2. `Private Sub UserForm_Activate()`

Answer (score 3):

O Initalize ocorre apenas uma vez em toda a execução do form então vc pode usar, por exemplo, pra adicionar items em um combo box, ou seja, colocar códigos que só precisar ser executados uma unica vez antes do formulario aparecer para o usuario. No caso do Activate, suponhamos que vc precisa fazer uma validação toda vez que o form é ativado, nesse caso você usaria o Activate já que ele sempre é executado quando o formulario é ativado

Comment: Pra ser bem sincero, não entendi sua explicação! Na verdade, não vi diferença! Como eles se dintinguem em termos práticos? Quando vc deve usar um em vez do outro?

Comment: O **Initalize** ocorre apenas uma vez em toda a execução do form então vc pode usar, por exemplo, pra adicionar items em um combo box, ou seja, colocar códigos que só precisar ser executados uma unica vez antes do formulario aparecer para o usuario. No caso do **Activate**, suponhamos que vc precisa fazer uma validação toda vez que o form é ativado, nesse caso você usaria o Activate já que ele sempre é executado quando o formulario é ativado

Comment: Legal! Fez mais sentido agora! Sugiro q vc atualize sua resposta com esse comentário pra ficar mais evidente para a comunidade ;)

Answer (score 0):

O **Inicialize** ocorre quando o objeto (no seu caso o Form) é **criado**. Então o código é executado **somente uma vez**. O **Activate** ocorre toda vez que o evento Activate do formulário ocorre, isto é, quando ele recebe foco, ou quando ele é exibido depois de ter sido ocultado, ou qualquer evento que ative o objeto.

[Referência da MS - Form.Activate Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activate?view=netframework-4.7.2)